# UFD and relatively prime elements

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I've found the following statement at page 9 of Griffiths, Harris "Principles of Algebraic Geometry":

*Proposition.* If $R$ is a UFD and $u$, $v \in R[t]$ are relatively prime, then there exist relatively prime elements $\alpha$, $\beta \in R[t]$ and $\gamma \in R$, $\gamma \neq 0$ such that $\alpha u + \beta v = \gamma$.

How to prove this proposition? There are no hints in the book, so any help is very welcome.

Comment: You are not quite sincere, there *is* a hint in the book: It says that $\gamma$ is the [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $u$ and $v$. The fact he states is a known property of resultants.